# printing rhombus numbers using a single loop?

Tags: java, c, for-loop

I am talking about printing this pattern

```
       1
      121
     12321
    1234321
   123454321
  12345654321
 1234567654321
123456787654321
```

It is very easy to do with using more than a single for loop. But I was trying to implement it using a single for loop but not able to do so.
Is it possible?

```
my code:- 

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
    System.out.println(sb.append(i)
    + new StringBuilder(sb).reverse().substring(1));
```

But I would really like to see how is it possible to see it being used with out any predefined functions like reverse() etc available that itself use a loop inside them. 
Just a simple single "for" loop.

Comment: We would really like to see, what you have tried so far

Comment: What do you mean by "single" loop? This is very vague term. Should it include loops inside methods/functions from libraries or not?

Comment: Yes, a clue: recursivity.

Comment: How will the loop understands when to stop? So please ask a valid questions

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/k60xSk)

Comment: @Andremoniy No! I am doing a programming course and this question was asked by my teacher just after we had finished with "for" loop. Many others did it using more than one "for" loops but my initial attempt was to do it using a "single for" loop. But I couldn't.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I see what you did there (͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: Does that pattern stop when n=9?

Comment: @Eric It depends on the input given.  In the code given in mine... n was 8

Comment: Why is this question so downvoted? I understand he hasn't provided code and such, but I feel like it is a perfectly valid question and may help other people.

Comment: What output do you want for n=10?

Comment: @Eric... 
If you look at the pattern that is being formed it is obvious for n = 10 the output should be 1234567891098765421

Comment: @pluto20010 missing `3`. typo ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to write out this pattern using only one loop:

```
class RhombusNumbers{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String left = "";
        int max = 8;
        for(int i = 1; i <= max; i++){
            System.out.println(left + i + new StringBuilder(left).reverse().toString());
            left+=i;
        }
    }

}
```

It keeps track of the left digits and adds a new digit on every time.

**EDIT:**

Without StringBuilder since StringBuilder.reverse() uses a loop and would also reverse a 10:

```
class RhombusNumbers{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String left = "";
        String right = "";
        int max = 8;
        for(int i = 1; i <= max; i++){
            System.out.println(left + i + right);
            left+=i;
            right = i + right;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `reverse()` function itself uses a loop inside

Comment: That's much better :-D

Comment: @Andremoniy fixed :p

Answer (score 3):

Using the fact that

```
1*1 = 1
11*11 = 121
111*111= 12321 
 ....
```

you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int j = 0;
    for(long i = 1 ; i<1000000000; i = i+(long)Math.pow(10, j)){
        System.out.println(i*i);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Totally forgot that that is a thing :p

Comment: Or `for(long i = 1; i<1000000000; i = i * 10 + 1) { System.out.println(i * i); }`.

Comment: This produces the "wrong" result after the first 9 numbers

Answer (score 1):

like this by C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    for(int i = 1, n = 1, d = 1; n <= 8; i += d){
        if(i == n){
            d = -d;
        } else if(i == 0){
            d = -d;
            ++n;
            puts("");
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sovle it with recursion:

```
class Rhombus {
  public static void left(int x) {
    if (--x > 0) {
      left(x);
      System.out.print(x);
    }
  }

  public static void right(int x) {
    if (--x > 0) {
      System.out.print(x)
      right(x);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      left(i);
      System.out.print(i);
      right(i);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
    System.out.println(sb.append(i)
        + new StringBuilder(sb).reverse().substring(1));
}
```

Comment: As commented byAndremoniy on my answer, StringBuilder.reverse() uses a loop. Therefore this is two loops.

Comment: String concatenation also uses loops in the form of `memcopy`, so I don't think that's relevant

Comment: This problem is inherently O(N^2), so is not solvable with a single loop of length N - there is always a hidden loop in that case.